# Can't check PGP signature for the Linux kernel source package

Tags: pgp, digital-signature

Just now I downloaded the [latest Linux kernel](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/linux-3.2.6.tar.bz2) from [the official site](http://www.kernel.org/). With it I downloaded the [.sign file](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/linux-3.2.6.tar.sign). I found instructions on-line for how to check the file against the PGP signature. It's the first time I'm doing something like this; I intend to compile the kernel to make it capable of reading [exFAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) file-systems.

However, when I want to check the file against the signature, I run into an error. I did [as instructed](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html) but I get the following:

[image: a snapshot of the error from the terminal]

P.S. I don't have a clue as to what the problem is here, for I have never dealt with PGP personally before. **I am not asking about how to make Ubuntu read exFAT**, please don't try to go that way and ignoring this PGP hassle. I want to compile the kernel and this is what is standing in the way now, so please help me solve *this problem*. Thanks for narrowing your answers.

Comment: It doesn't look like gpg is failing but rather the file is inaccessible. Check the permissions and group settings for both files.

Comment: @Amazed Hey, that's not the problem at all. I checked the permissions, they're all right. I also run the command as root; same results. I did this _before_ I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading it again. With wget. Perhaps the download wasn't perfect. Does it even untar/unxz without any errors? You also don't need the archive in your command line. Just include the .sign file and have them in the same directory.